# How to check if a registry key exists

Tags: delphi, registry

I don't know wheres my mistake. It always jumps to the `else` branch, but the key exist, I checked it several times.

```
var
  reg : TRegistry;
begin
    with TRegistry.Create do try
      RootKey:=HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
      OpenKey('\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', False);
    if KeyExists('nginx.exe') then begin
      ShowMessage('Ja geht ist da');
      Result := True;
      btnAutostart.ImageIndex := 5
    end
    else begin
      Result := False;
      btnAutostart.ImageIndex := 0;
    end;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to call `ValueExists` rather than `KeyExists`. A key is what appears as a folder in Regedit but you are looking for a value named `nginx.exe` in the key `HKCU\Software\...\Run`.

Some other comments:

1. Since you are only reading from the registry, use `OpenKeyReadOnly` rather than `OpenKey`.
2. Check the return value of `OpenKeyReadOnly` in case the key cannot be opened.
3. If you actually need to do this with HKLM (as you state in a comment), watch out for registry redirection confusion when running 32 bit process on 64 bit system.

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer. Now its working. But it didnt worked because an other mistake. i used current user not HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE like in the other procedure for writing the autostart <.<