# Creating 7 registry values under a registry key without repetition

Tags: .net, vb.net, permissions, registry, repeat

I am developing an windows application using vb.net. Now I want to add 7 values in registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MYAPP`.

Each value (out of 7) should be added only when it does not exist in the subkey.

In the end I want to see only 7 under `MYAPP` SUBKEY. How do I do that? I need your help.

Comment: I don't do VB.NET but would imagine there is a function like "keyexists". You could do 'If Not Keyexists('YourKey') then...' Either add the key or move on.

Comment: The structure of windows registry is that in a key we have valuename with a value. And I want to programmatically create a new value (not key) with a different valuename.

Comment: Same should apply, if valueexist... etc. This link is delphi but it might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938305/how-to-check-if-a-registry-key-exists

Comment: Registry values match a Dictionary(Of String, Object).  Use the `For Each` keyword to iterate it.

Comment: How should their respective valuenames be programatically?

Comment: Your latest comment is not valid English, please rephrase it. -- As for your question, this article should provide you with the basics you need: [**Reading from and Writing to the Registry**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85t3c3hf.aspx).

Comment: each value should correspond to its name (valueName). I know how to check if value exists and I know how to create a value. My question is how to create 7 different values programmatically with each having a valueName?

Comment: Create the key, then use foreach to iterate the 7 values. Inside foreach add the value if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GetValue` of a `RegistryKey` object and test the result, if `Nothing` then the value does not exist.

Here is a complete example that should get you working. Note that you *might* need admin rights to create keys and values depending on the machine permissions:

```
    Dim myAppKey = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.CurrentUser, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Default)
    If myAppKey Is Nothing Then Throw New Exception("Failed to open registry")

    Dim subKeyName = "SOFTWARE\MYAPP"

    'attempt to open the subkey with write acces because we need this if we are creating values
    Dim subKey = myAppKey.OpenSubKey(subKeyName, True)
    If subKey Is Nothing Then
        'create the sub key because it doesn't exist
        myAppKey.CreateSubKey(subKeyName)
        're open the new key
        subKey = myAppKey.OpenSubKey(subKeyName, True)
    End If

    'create values in a loop for testing
    For i = 0 To 6
        If subKey.GetValue("Value" & i) Is Nothing Then
            'value does not exist so create it
            subKey.SetValue("Value" & i, i)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Matt, this works like a charm. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You are welcome - Please upvote as well if this answer helped you